# .3mf files in system folder "3D Objects" that I don't recall seeing before

Tags: windows, windows-10, 3d

I just turned on an old computer and found there are multiple .3mf files in system folder "3D Objects" that I don't recall seeing before, as shown below.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKhc8.png)

I don't recall seeing these files before so my first thought was that they are just files that came with an update as demos, but I haven't used this computer for a while so I might've just forgotten that I put them there.

My computer is a Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are they just files that came with an update as demos, or did I put them there and forget?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the demo set of 3D-Objects. You just forgot:
[image]

Comment: I seem to have more of these files... probably just a different version of the set tho. Thanks!